# Confusing code involving lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

All, these are the codes making me confused:

```
arg_dict = conf.copy()
args = lambda var: arg_dict[var]
args.func_dict = arg_dict
```

I know the basics of lambda but I don't understand what it is trying to do here.

`conf` is a predefined dict like this:

```
conf = {
    "port":     None,
    "host":     None,
    "query":    None,
    "no_serve": None,
    "no_load":  None,
    "debug":    None,
}
```

Comment: `print type(args)` may help you understand this code. But please, **what is your question**? Apart from being confused.

Comment: I don't know what the `func_dict` bit is supposed to accomplish, but the first two lines are simply defining a function that retrieves a value corresponding to a given key from a dict.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: There is a pretty neat trick being played here; it is the `args.func_dict = arg_dict` line that should have caught your attention.

Comment: @Asad: and it is the `func_dict` bit that is making this interesting.

Comment: `args` is exactly the same as `arg_dict.__getitem__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup, saw your answer. Learn something every day.

Comment: @chepner: except that it also supports translating attribute access to `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code uses a `lambda` expression to create a function object that looks up arguments in the given dictionary when called, *and* lets you look up keys as attributes instead. The `conf` dictionary presumably functions as a template here; it is copied so that the original is not modified when you assign more keys to it.

Both of these two lines will return the value for `conf['debug']`:

```
args.debug
args('debug')
```

It'll also translate setting attributes on the `args` function object into setting a value for a key in the `arg_dict` dictionary:

```
args.foo = 'bar'
```

translates to

```
args_dict['foo'] = 'bar'
```

That's because the `func_dict` attribute of a function forms the attribute namespace of the function object. This is normally an empty dictionary, letting you set arbitrary attributes on the function object. By *replacing* that with the predefined dictionary you get to share the dictionary with the function body for some neat tricks.

The `func_dict` attribute is documented in the [Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), under *User-defined functions*:

> `__dict__`, `func_dict`
>   The namespace supporting arbitrary function attributes.
>   Writable

`__dict__` is another name for the same attribute.

Demo:

```
>>> conf = {
...     "port":     None,
...     "host":     None,
...     "query":    None,
...     "no_serve": None,
...     "no_load":  None,
...     "debug":    None,
... }
>>> arg_dict = conf.copy()
>>> args = lambda var: arg_dict[var]
>>> args.func_dict = arg_dict
>>> args('debug')
>>> args.debug
>>> args.debug = 'bar'
>>> args('debug')
'bar'
>>> args.debug
'bar'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Very detailed and helpful :)  A lot for me to learn.